# Prove that an open ball in $\Bbb R^2$ is connected

Tags: general-topology

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show that it's path connected: for any point, there's a straight line path (contained in the ball) to the center of the ball, and from there, a straight line to any other point.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but how do I prove that there is a path between any two points inside the ball?

Comment: Let the radius of the ball be $r$. Let the center be $x$, the first point to be $y$. Consider the path $\gamma(t) = (1-t)y + tx$. This satisfies $\gamma(0) = y, \gamma(1) = x$. Further, $|\gamma(t) - x| = |(1-t)y + (t-1)x| = (1-t)|y-x| \leq |y-x| < r$ for all $t$, so the path lies entirely in the ball.

Comment: Actually, I am having a problem over the fact that as     f: [0,1] to R2 , f(t)= (1-t)x + ty is continuous, then f([0,1]) is connected . Then as unit ball in R2 is an ordered set in the order topology, by IVP of f  any point between x=0*1 and y=1*0 must have a pre-image in [0,1] , but by the dictionary order topology, 0*1< z=1/2*(√3/2) < 1*0 , but z has no pre-image under f. Why ?????

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Let $U=\left\{\, x\in\R^n : \|x\|<1\, \right\}$ be the open unit ball. For any $x\in U$ we have the straight line path
\begin{align}
\gamma : [0,1] &\longrightarrow \R^n \\
t &\longmapsto tx
\end{align}
from $0$ to $x$. Since
$$
\|tx\| = t\|x\| \le \|x\| <1
$$
this is a path in $U$. Therefore $U$ is path connected, which implies $U$ is connected.

Answer (score 1):

For a separation $U,V$ (both non-empty) of the given ball take $u_0 \in U ,v_0 \in V$ . Take the line segment joining the two points (call it $L$). $L$ is connected. But $L \cap U ,L \cap V$ is a separation of $L$ ,a contradiction.

Comment: I know, but we didn't define convex sets yet.

Comment: Here's the edited version.